# How to select a random cell in a Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to select a random cell from a preset grid (Ex. A1 - D4)

I tried using a random number generator to pick a number (1-9 in this case), and set each number equal to a cell. My end goal is for the A1 cell to display whatever text is in the randomly chosen cell (for example, if I changed B2 to say "Test1" and is randomly selected, I would like A1 to display "Test1").

[image]

The exact code I tried: =(RANDBETWEEN(1,9));(IF(A1=1,B2,IF(A1=2,C2,IF(A1=3,D2,IF(A1=4,B3,If(A1=5,C3,IF(A1=6,D3,IF(A1=7,B4,IF(A1=8,C4,IF(A1=9,D4))))))))))

Comment: The exact code I tried: =(RANDBETWEEN(1,9));(IF(A1=1,B2,IF(A1=2,C2,IF(A1=3,D2,IF(A1=4,B3,If(A1=5,C3,IF(A1=6,D3,IF(A1=7,B4,IF(A1=8,C4,IF(A1=9,D4))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to get a random cell in the range (in this case `A1:B9`):

```cpp
=LET(
  r,
  A1:B9,
  OFFSET(
    r,
    RANDBETWEEN(0, ROWS(r)-1),
    RANDBETWEEN(0, COLUMNS(r)-1),
    1,
    1
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) combined with [`RANDARRAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9211904?hl=en), this is particularly useful if you want to return a sub-array with N random values, but it works fine with 1 random value as well.

For example, the following formula returns a random value from the range `A1:D4` while ignoring empty cells.

```cpp
=SORTN(TOCOL(A1:D4,1),1,,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A1:D4)),)
```

Answer (score 0):

=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(1,26)+64)&RANDBETWEEN(1,1000)